# R - Formatting dates in dataframe - mix of decimal and character values

Tags: r, lubridate, openxlsx

I have a date column in a dataframe. I have read this df into R using openxlsx. The column is 'seen' as a character vector when I use `typeof(df$date)`.

The column contains date information in several formats and I am looking to get this into the one format.

```
#Example
date <- c("43469.494444444441", "12/31/2019 1:41 PM", "12/01/2019  16:00:00")

#What I want -updated
fixed <- c("2019-04-01", "2019-12-31", "2019-12-01")
```

I have tried many work arounds including `openxlsx::ConvertToDate`, `lubridate::parse_date_time`, `lubridate::date_decimal`

`openxlsx::ConvertToDate`so far works best but it will only take 1 format and coerce NAs for the others

**update**

I realized I actually had one of the above output dates wrong.
Value 43469.494444444441 should convert to 2019-04-01.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a helper function to normalize the dates which might be slightly faster than `lubridate`.

There are [weird origins in MS Excel](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-March/270455.html) that depend on platform. So if the data are imported from different platforms, you may want to work woth dummy variables.

```
normDate <- Vectorize(function(x) {
if (!is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))))  # Win excel
  as.Date(as.numeric(x), origin="1899-12-30")
else if (grepl("A|P", x))
  as.Date(x, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p")
else
  as.Date(x, format="%m/%d/%Y %R")
})
```

For additional date formats just add another `else if`. Format specifications can be found with `?strptime`.

Then just use `as.Date()` with usual origin.

```
res <- as.Date(normDate(date), origin="1970-01-01")
# 43469.494444444441   12/31/2019 1:41 PM 12/01/2019  16:00:00 
#       "2019-01-04"         "2019-12-31"         "2019-12-01"
class(res)
# [1] "Date"
```

***Edit:*** To achieve a specific output format, use `format`, e.g.

```
format(res, "%Y-%d-%m")
# 43469.494444444441   12/31/2019 1:41 PM 12/01/2019  16:00:00 
#       "2019-04-01"         "2019-31-12"         "2019-01-12" 

format(res, "%Y/%d/%m")
# 43469.494444444441   12/31/2019 1:41 PM 12/01/2019  16:00:00 
#       "2019/04/01"         "2019/31/12"         "2019/01/12"
```

To lookup the codes type `?strptime`.

Comment: This seems to work the best. Only in my actual df some of the dates have the day and month incorrect e.g. 10Apr19 is reported as 2019-10-04 instead of 2019-04-10

Comment: Does `as.Date("10Apr19", format="%d%b%y")` do the job? You can lookup more format strings typing `?strptime`.

Comment: Thanks jay.sf, the date 10Apr19 is present in my df as 43469.494444444441 I want R to present as 2019-04-10 but when I use the code above it reports it as 2019-10-04

Comment: Thanks jay.sf but if you look above the other dates are now incorrect. I think the data is just too much of a mess to work with. Thanks so much for your help though :)

Comment: @AudileF Is it better when you wrap the `format()` inside the formula, i.e. `format(as.Date(as.numeric(x), origin="1899-12-30"), "%Y-%d-%m")`?

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to do this in two-step. Change excel dates separately and all other dates differently. If you have some more formats of dates that can be added in `parse_date_time`.

```
temp <- lubridate::parse_date_time(date, c('mdY IMp', 'mdY HMS'))
temp[is.na(temp)] <- as.Date(as.numeric(date[is.na(temp)]), origin = "1899-12-30")

temp
#[1] "2019-01-04 11:51:59 UTC" "2019-12-31 13:41:00 UTC" "2019-12-01 16:00:00 UTC"
as.Date(temp)
#[1] "2019-01-04" "2019-12-31" "2019-12-01"
```

Comment: Thanks I like this solution. Worked for me when I was using read_excel